# Prove probability measure over power set of integers exists (and satisfies condition stated below)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Having some degree of trouble trying to solve this question. Firstly, let us call the power set of the integers $A$. I want to find a function $p: A \to [0,1]$ where the function $p$ satisfies:

1) $p(\mathbb{Z}) = 1$

2) for $a, b \in A$, if $a\cap b = \emptyset \hspace{1mm}$ then $\hspace{1mm}p(a\cup b) = p(a) + p(b)$

I.e. it is a probability measure but only finitely additive. The additional condition on this function is given below. Let $a \in A$ and define:

$f_n(a) = \frac{|a \cap\{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}|}{n+1}$ (intepreted as the proportion of the first $n+1$ integers in $a$).

Let $\overline{f}(a) = \lim \sup_n f_n(a)\hspace{4mm}$ and $\hspace{4mm}\underline{f}(a) = \lim \inf_n f_n(a)$

I have to ensure that $\overline{f}(a) \geq p(a) \geq \underline{f}(a)$.

The textbook had me check whether $p(a) = \frac{\overline{f}(a) + \underline{f}(a)}{2}$ was a valid function and I produced a counter-example to that already. I however, do not have much intuition on how to proceed from there. Does such a function exist? If so could you give me a hint on how to tackle it? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "a power set $A$ of the integers"? There is only one power set of the integers. Also, it's a contradiction that $p$ is a probability measure and that it does not have to be $\sigma$-additive, as countable additivity is part of the definition of a probability measure.

Comment: @joriki sorry, that was poor wording of me, I meant the power set of the integers, which I denote $A$. Also, it seems that my textbook went and defined probability measure as only finitely additive. In both cases I have tweaked the wording of my question to avoid confusion.